# background-size get's ignored with ngStyle Angular2

Tags: javascript, css, angular

When I inspect the element in Chrome I get the `display: block;` but `background-size: cover;` is nowhere.

Do you have an idea what could cause this?

This is my code:

```
 <div class="image-slides" [ngStyle]="{'background': 'linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)), url(' + (items | async)?.img_paths[0]+ ') center center no-repeat','display': 'block', 'background-size': 'cover'}">
   <ion-icon class="back-icon" (click)="goBack()" color="light" name="ios-arrow-round-back"></ion-icon>
   <ion-icon class="fav-icon" color="light" name="star"></ion-icon>
   <h1>Hello {{(items | async)?.name}}</h1>
 </div>
```

Comment: Please let me know if my answer was helpful or I should delete it (not to confuse future readers)

Comment: @KostasSiabanis can't say. Solved it another way but don't remember how.

Answer (score -1):

You should escape quotes in `url(' + (items | async)?.img_paths[0]+ ')` like this:

```
[ngStyle]="{'background': 'linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)), url(\' + (items | async)?.img_paths[0]+ \') center center no-repeat','display': 'block', 'background-size': 'cover'}"
```

Comment: Voting down without commenting does not contribute much to anyone. Would love to know how I can improve and help others improve.